# jmeter json path bean post processor

Tags: jmeter

I have following entries that got extracted from Response using `JSONPath` extractor

```
entries = ["e-1553","e-1552","c-1052","e-1551","c-1050",
           "e-1550","c-1049","e-1549","c-1051","e-1548",
           "c-1048","e-1547","c-1047","e-1546","c-1045",
           "e-1545","e-1544","c-1046","e-1543","e-1542",
           "c-1026","e-1541","e-1540","e-1539","e-1538",
           "c-1025","e-1537","e-1536","c-1024","f-1535",
           "f-1534"]
```

I want to Iterate only over those entries that start with "`e-`" e.g. "`e-1553,e-1552"` etc. in my ForEach Controller and exclude other entries such as `"c-1052, c-1050"` etc.

So that I can use http://somesite.com/e-1553 etc.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have "entries" variable which holds that JSONArray you can get all the entries which start from "e-" as follows:

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) **after** the JSONPath Extractor
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   JSONArray array = JSONArray.fromObject(vars.get("entries"));
   int counter = 0;
   for (int i=0;i < array.size();i++) {
       String s = array.get(i).toString();
       if (s.startsWith("e-"))
       {
           counter++;
           vars.put("entry_" + counter, s);
       }
   }
   ```

It will produce variables like:

```
entry_1=e-1553
entry_10=e-1544
entry_11=e-1543
entry_12=e-1542
entry_13=e-1541
etc.
```

Then add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) and configure it as follows:

- Input variable prefix: `entry`
- Start index for loop: `0`
- Output variable name: `current_entry`

Then in HTTP Request use `${current_entry}` in the Path.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.